# Dropdown Menu Opening Bat File

Tags: java, netbeans

I need some help.I have a Java program with a drop-down menu,there is an option in that menu to launch a test.bat file, what code would I use to specify the system path for it to open test.bat? Test.bat is an external file for testing purposes.

**EDIT**

This problem has been resolved.

Comment: What have you tried so far that doesn't work? Use the relative path to the file and execute the file from the Runtime?

Comment: I haven't tried anything because i'v only been learning java for about a day.Please can you explain to me what Runtime is.It must use the relative file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File f = new File("test.bat");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
```

Comment: This is perfect, would there be anyway for me to add a direct file path instead of having it on the desktop?

Comment: I get this error when I try to run the program:
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: test.bat doesn't exist.`
I made the file test.bat, it does exist...

Comment: test.bat should be in your project folder or try to give absolute path.

Comment: I have the file in my project folder like so: http://gyazo.com/6e2300148f3e102af11b05d037e807eb
I still get the error :/
You can see the code at the top of this page under edit.

Comment: paste your file in some drive and then try with absolute path

Comment: Drive means `C:\` drive